# EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/stefma/.config/truffle/config.json' after installing Truffle

Tags: npm-install, permission-denied, macos-big-sur, truffle

I tried literally all there is so far and I still can't run truffle macOS 11.6.
that's what I tried after of course first installing it with the command `npm install -g truffle`:

1. Downloading command line tools for Xcode and then installing with
   `sudo npm install -g truffle`
2. `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root truffle`
3. `sudo chown myUsername:myUsername -R ~/.config`
4. installing npm and node with nvm all over.

I'd be really grateful for any help

Answer (score 2):

This should work kindly check [YourMacOSUserName] in fir place you MacOSUserName in it and please must rate my effort will be here for any further query.

> sudo rm -rf /Users/[YourMacOSUserName]/Library/Preferences/netlify/

> npm install -g netlify-cli

> sudo ntl login